# CSS change color of image

Tags: css, css-filters

I have a few icon images which include only a white outline and a transparent background.
How can I use CSS (filters, etc) to display those icons in any color I choose?
I tried a combination of a few CSS filters (hue-rotate, brightness, etc) but with limited success... I guess my knowledge in color theory is very limited.

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you have a look at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: is this png jpeg svg images?

Comment: you could use canvas instead...

Comment: I have png images... I would need to convert them to a font, to use font-awesome, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property `background-color` for the image container. Here is an demonstration.

```js
$( "a" ).click(function() {
  $( "div" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vpc3.png");
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="vclick" href="#">Click to change color</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I needed to change the color of the outline, not the background